# parse multiple parquet files with s3 select in python?

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet

I'm trying to read multiple parquet files from a single S3 bucket subfolder with boto3.

I've had no problem reading a single csv file with python, but I have'nt been able to get it to work with multiple file readings before.

I have seen previous answers that this is not supported by aws. However, as I understand, this functionality has been implemented in the end of 2018.

So, is there a way, using my working code (shown below) to run a s3 `select` statement for all the parquet files in the relevant folder, i.e. select all the rows from all the files?

Files in the working subfolder in a bucket:

```
_success
file1.snapy.parquet
file2.snapy.parquet
```

python code:

```
response = s3.select_object_content(
            Bucket='somebucket',
            Key= 'pathtosubfolder',
            ExpressionType='SQL', <br>
            InputSerialization = {'Parquet': {}},
            Expression="select * from s3object s ",
            OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
            )
```

I expected the sql statement outcome, however I'm getting:

> `[ERROR] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the
>   SelectObjectContent operation: The specified key does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/) if you want to query collections of parquet format objects in an S3.

Athena is fully managed [Facebook Presto](https://prestodb.io/) service.